# Modal Form Submission

Tags: ajax, modal-dialogs

I have a modal form that I added to my module and patterned it after this  [article](https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/loading-and-rendering-modal-forms-drupal-8/).

I have used it before with no issues, I was able to use the method to show the form and then save the data.

Now I am populating the form as an edit form.  When I submit the form it calls the controller again, which calls the `buildForm()` method of the modal class and then wipes out the data that was entered into the form.  The data was in the `$form_state` correct but after the `buildForm()` runs it finally get to the AJAX call back handler and the data is no longer in the `$form_state`. It is totally gone.  I am not sure how to solve this.  I can't update anything in Drupal based on the form submit.

```
TimeOffApprovalController.php (Entry point of the route)

namespace Drupal\timeoff\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\OpenModalDialogCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder;

class TimeOffApprovalController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * The form builder.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder
   */
  protected $formBuilder;

  /**
   * The ModalFormExampleController constructor.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder $formBuilder
   *   The form builder.
   */
  public function __construct(FormBuilder $formBuilder) {
    $this->formBuilder = $formBuilder;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   *
   * @param \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface $container
   *   The Drupal service container.
   *
   * @return static
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('form_builder')
    );
  }

  /**
   * Callback for opening the modal form.
   */
  public function openModalForm($id) {
    $response = new AjaxResponse();

    // Get the modal form using the form builder.
    $modal_form = $this->formBuilder->getForm('Drupal\timeoff\Form\TimeOffApprovalForm', $id);

    // Add an AJAX command to open a modal dialog with the form as the content.
    $response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand('Approval Form', $modal_form, ['width' => '800']));

    return $response;
  }

}
```

TimeOffApprovalForm.php (Modal form)

```
namespace Drupal\timeoff\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\OpenModalDialogCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\ReplaceCommand;
use Drupal\timeoff\Controller\TimeOffController;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\RedirectCommand;

class TimeOffApprovalForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'modal_form_example_modal_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $options = NULL) {
    $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="modal_example_form">';
    $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

    // The status messages that will contain any form errors.
    $form['status_messages'] = [
      '#type' => 'status_messages',
      '#weight' => -10,
    ];

    $ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('time_off_day')
                  ->condition('timeoffid', $options)
                  ->execute();
    $entitys = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('time_off_day')->loadMultiple($ids);

    $deny_dropdown = array();
    $hours_value = array();

    foreach ($entitys as $the_entity) {
      $deny_dropdown[$the_entity->id()] = t($the_entity->label());
      $hours_value[$the_entity->id()] = $the_entity->getTimeOffHours();
      $form[$the_entity->getTimeOffDate()] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t($the_entity->getTimeOffDate()),
        '#value' => t($the_entity->getTimeOffHours()),
        '#required' => TRUE,
      );
    }

    $form['timeoffid'] = array(
      '#type' => 'hidden',
      '#value' => $options,
    );
    $form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
    $form['actions']['send'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit Approval form'),
      '#attributes' => [
        'class' => [
          'use-ajax',
        ],
      ],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => [$this, 'submitApprovalFormAjax'],
        'event' => 'click',
      ],
    ];

    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * AJAX callback handler that displays any errors or a success message.
   */
  public function submitApprovalFormAjax(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $response = new AjaxResponse();

    // If there are any form errors, re-display the form.
    if ($form_state->hasAnyErrors()) {
      $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#modal_example_form', $form));
    }
    else {

      // Do the time off denial
      //$id = $form_state->getValue('timeoffid');
      //$denialid = $form_state->getValue('deny_reason');
      //$comment = $form_state->getValue('deny_comment');
      //$timeoffcontroller = new TimeOffController();
      //$timeoffcontroller->deny($id, $denialid, $comment);

      $referer_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
      $response->addCommand(new RedirectCommand($referer_url));
    }

    foreach ($form_state->getValues() as $key => $value) {
      drupal_set_message($key . ': ' . $value);
    }

    return $response;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {}

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {}

  /**
   * Gets the configuration names that will be editable.
   *
   * @return array
   *   An array of configuration object names that are editable if called in
   *   conjunction with the trait's config() method.
   */
  protected function getEditableConfigNames() {
    return ['config.modal_form_example_modal_form'];
  }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: I am doing some more testing and have determined that the values array for the form_state is not being populated with any data.  I do see the date in the _POST.  I am not sure why it is not placing the submitted data in the values array.

Comment: Try populating the form fields with `#default_value =>`.... instead of `#value`

Comment: @theuni - That worked great.  How do I give you credit for that?  I can't believe I did not pick that up.  I feel like sometimes you can reet 100 pages and not see something.

Comment: Good it's working now! If you want you can upvote my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Populating a form field should be done via `'#default_value' => ...` instead of `'#value' => ...`